# Check if directory exists using ADB and push a file if it does

Tags: android, batch-file, adb

I need to be able to test and see if a directory exists on the SD card of an Android device and then push a few files to that directory if it does exist.

So far, I have this:

```
adb %argument% shell if [ -e /sdcard/ ]; then echo "it does exist"; else echo "it does not exist"; fi;
```

But how can I let my batch script know that the directory exists so that it can continue to push the file to that directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I have done in batch script:

```
set cmd="adb shell ls | find /c "theFile" "
FOR /F %%K IN (' !cmd! ') DO SET TEST=%%K
if !TEST! GTR 0 (
    echo the file exists
) else (
    echo the file does not exist
)
```

There could be multiple files that fit the fileName, so I chose to have it test greater than 0.

---

To test for exact match and using bash in Linux ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13013379/427763)):

```
FILENAME_RESULT=$(adb shell ls / | tr -d '\015'|grep '^fileName$')

if [ -z "$FILENAME_RESULT" ];
then
        echo "No fileName found."
else
        echo "fileName found."
fi
```

Comment: Where is the 1st one supposed to run at? Windows?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should list directory `dir or ls` and next analyze out using grep. If grep found directory script do something.

Comment: No grep on windows machine. And prefer not to download an outside utility to accomplish this goal.

Comment: I am already aware of `find`, but how am i supposed to use find to set some flag telling my next command to `push` a file to the device?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for the assistance and pointing me to a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

1) Just use adb shell ls /filepath > fileifpresent

2) grep locally if "No such file or directory" present, then NO

```
 Else Directory Present
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'll do it checking for the exit status of the command

```
MyFile="Random.txt"
WorkingPath="/data/local/tmp/RandomFolder"

IsDir=`adb shell ls $WorkingPath &> /dev/null ; echo "$?"`

if [ $IsDir == 0 ] ; then 

   echo "Exist! Copying File To Remote Folder"

   adb push $MyFile $WorkingPath

else

   echo "Folder Don't Exist! Creating Folder To Start Copying File"

   adb shell mkdir $WorkingPath

   adb push $MyFile $WorkingPath

fi
```