# grep exact match

Tags: android, linux, grep, adb

I need to `grep` for an exact match on a list of results from an `ls` command.

For example, if i `ls` a directory and here are the results:

```
system
sys
sbin
proc
init.rc
init.mahimahi.rc
init.goldfish.rc
init
```

I would like to `grep` to see if a file exists that is named "init". I need the `grep` to only return the one result. There is only one file named "init" in the list.

---

I am performing this operation on an android device. So here is the full command:

```
adb shell ls / | grep -E "^init$"
```

---

I need to check the existence of a directory on the android device and then perform an action if the directory exists.

I have done this before using `find` in a batch script, but i need to do this on linux using `bash` and i want an exact match. This will avoid the issue if there is another directory or file that contains the string i am searching for.

---

I have tried the suggestions in the following links, but they all return no result when i give "init" as the parameter.

[how-to-grep-the-exact-match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709912/how-to-grep-the-exact-match)

[match-exact-word-using-grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718457/match-exact-word-using-grep)

Comment: Why don't you simply test for the existence of that file instead?

Comment: Erm... you mean `grep -E '^init$'` doesn't work?

Comment: If the issue is to avoid having the dot meaning any character, you could escape it with a backslash as `\\.` or perhaps use `fgrep`

Comment: As a matter of fact, I think `test -e init` would be even more straightforward. Will `adb shell test -e /init` return anything? )

Comment: GREP is an acronym.  It stands for "Global Regular Expression Print".  If you "grep" for a fixed string, you're wasting resources.  [What are you REALLY trying to do](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)?

Comment: @raina77ow: `adb shell ls / | grep -e /init` did not return anything.

Comment: @prolink007 - `grep -e /init` does NOT mean the same thing as `grep -E '^init$'` or `test -e /init`.

Comment: @ghoti: I have tried both of those as well, earlier, and neither worked. Still nothing is being returned.

Comment: You can't mix and match one command with the options of another command.  Tell us what you are trying to achieve, and we'll try to help.  If all you want is to see if `/init` exists, then `test -e /init` is the way to go.  Beyond that, we need to know your goal before we can give you an appropriate answer.

Comment: @ghoti: My goal is clearly stated in my question. And i am not mixing and matching. I am doing exactly as people are posting and seeing no result returned. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: @prolink007 - no, you've stated what you're trying to achieve, not why you're trying to achieve it.  The way to determine whether a file called "init" exists in your root directory is the `test` command, not grep.  And you specifically told us that you were trying your command line with the options for `test` applied to `grep`.  Again: tell us what you're really trying to achieve. You've only asked us to help you implement your solution to whatever problem you're facing.

Comment: @ghoti: You said, "Tell us what you are trying to achieve" initially. I will answer your new question of "why you're trying to achieve it". And i did answer "Tell us what you are trying to achieve" in my question. I will add the additional information to my question.

Comment: @prolink007 - my mistake, I should have been more explicit in my request for a bigger pocture.  I figured that the link to the "XY Problem" page would be a sufficient hint for you.

Comment: just curious, why don't you use `if [ -f init ]` as opposed to piping `ls` to `grep`?

Comment: @doubleDown: Because i am not looking on the file system of my computer. I am looking on the file system of the android device using the `ADB`. I do not believe that will work through the `ADB`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the ls file has nothing to do with the filesystem (so that you can't use the filesystem instead), `grep '^init$'` should do the trick.

---

xxd results:

```
00000a0: 2e67 6f6c 6466 6973 682e 7263 0d0a 696e  .goldfish.rc..in
00000b0: 6974 0d0a 6465 6661 756c 742e 7072 6f70  it..default.prop
```

based on this hexdump, I'd suggest that you turn it to unix-style first:

```
adb shell ls /|tr -d '\015'|grep '^init$'
```

Comment: This is not working. I am performing this operation on an android device through the `ADB`. Check my additional information in the post.

Comment: I have no android devices around, if it doesn't work, what exactly happens?

Comment: It returns nothing. I expect to see "init" returned.

Comment: I suspect there are extra characters returned. Can you try piping it to `xdd` and see if there's something else?

Comment: Not sure what `xdd` is, but i re-directed it to a text file and then viewed the file with formatting and white space. I see no extra hidden characters with "init".

Comment: `xdd` is mistyped `xxd`, which is hexdump. If you provide dump it should be obvious if it's an issue. What happens if you do just `grep init` — do you get expected results?

Comment: I get
`init.rc
init.mahimahi.rc
init.goldfish.rc
init`. I expect to only see "init" returning. I am going to add my results from the `xxd` to your answer. Remove them from your answer as soon as you have viewed them. This way there is no clutter. Thanks

Comment: Okay, it seems to be the line ending problem

Comment: But do pay attention to what ghoti says — the way to test for file's existence using remote `test` may be a better way. The question is, though, whether adb also passess the return code back. You could do something like `adb shell 'test -e /init && echo yes'` if it doesn't.

Comment: You must have root access for `test`. I get a permission denied result when attempting `test`.

Comment: you need no root access to test for file existence, I'm sure. There's probably something else that goes wrong. Anyway, did adding dot help?

Comment: Trying `grep '^init.$'` resulted in a newline between my two prompts. Typically there is no newline appearing. I am still expecting to see "init" returned.

Comment: You probably got init overwritten. Try the updated answer :)

Comment: That worked, but why? What is `tr` and `\015` doing?

Comment: Kills the `\015` — `\r` from the input.

Answer (score 0):

To get an exact match you have to activate regular expressions with the -E parameter and use beginning of line and end of line symbols:

```
grep -E "^init$"
```

Comment: Nah, you don't need to activate extended regex for `^$`. Doesn't do any harm either.

Comment: This is not working. I am performing this operation on an android device through the `ADB`. Check my additional information in the post.

Comment: Since I commented on the answer, I feel obliged to say I did NOT downvote ;-) But the reason might be your misleading wording — you don't need `-E` to enable regex for grep, `-E` enables *extended* regex.

Answer (score 0):

Are there problems with `grep`? How about `awk`?

```
ls | awk '$1 == "init"'
```

Comment: Well, yes, but changing the tool in hope it will solve the problem without identifying the problem is not the best way to deal with it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The question is which shell (the device or your pc) you want to do shell expansion/grepping/etc?

If you want your device to do the processing, the command should be

```
adb shell "ls / | grep ^init$"
```

If you want your pc to do the job, the command would be

```
adb shell "ls /" | tr -d '\r' | grep ^init$
```

But then again, as many others suggested, when you know the exact file name - just check if it exists, no need for grepping

```
adb shell "[ -f '/init' ] && echo 'found'"
```